# Increase the temporary disk size in azure vm

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have a test service fabric deployed to a single node VM. It is all working, but the temporary disk drive is only 20GB is size and keeps running out. I'm only using an A2_V2 Standard instance to keep tests down while we are testing things out.

Service Fabric is using the temporary disk for storage.

Is there a way to increase the size of the temporary disk?

Answer (score 2):

Azure temporary disk size depends on your VM size. If you want to change its size, you need to resize your VM. However, the temporary disk will lost data if you resize the VM. Because**The temporary disk is not  persisted.**

> Temporary Disk
>
> The temporary storage drive, labeled as the D: drive is not persisted
>   and is not saved in the Windows Azure Blob storage. It is used
>   primarily for the page file and its performance is not guaranteed to
>   be predictable. Management tasks such as a change to the virtual
>   machine size, resets the D: drive. In addition, Windows Azure erases
>   the data on the temporary storage drive when a virtual machine fails
>   over. The D: drive is not recommended for storing any user or system
>   database files, including tempdb.

So, I don't suggest you use the temporary disk as the storage for the Service Fabric. You can [add data disk to your VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/attach-managed-disk-portal).

Comment: Hi, @Slicc, if this answer is helpful to you , please mark it as answer, so that we can help more people. Thanks~